# pip install numpy on windows 10 showed successful result, but no numpy is in site-package folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, numpy, pip

I have python 3.7 and need to install numpy. I used pip install numpy. Command line shows it is successful. But when I go to the site-package folder. numpy is not there. So `import numpy` will not work.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.20.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (13.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.3
```

What could be causing this issue? Is there an verbose output for pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python 3 you need to use the command 'pip3' instead of 'pip'!!

Additional information:
I think you need to configure your Python to look where your Modules are installed.

Here is where the module might be installed: C:\Users<installUser>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib

You may try moving the install to a new path, correcting your 'PATH' variable, and try it again.

To summarize, it could be permissions, could be the install location...

Here is a link to some documentation:
https://realpython.com/lessons/why-cant-python-find-my-modules/

Here is a link to Virtual Environment setups. The doc above mentions this as a possible solution. I use these for Ansible with WSL, and I love them: https://realpython.com/courses/working-python-virtual-environments/

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! Here is why I can't find the module even if pip install showed to be successful. pip install commands created
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\site-packages
And put numpy and a bunch of files over there instead of the correct folder. But I still got error when import numpy, istributor_init.py", line 32
    stacklevel=1)
UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs   The error seems to be related to two gofortran dlls. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: It is most likely an issue with your PATH variable. I would make sure it is pointed to the right place. The Virtual Environment is a way around that problem if you can't figure it out that way. I wish you the best of luck!!

Comment: Here, I suppose there is something we can do. Run a 'pip list' and see if you can find numpy

Comment: Hey Shusen, 
I added an update to my answer. Use 'pip3' instead of pip. Enjoy